# What part of speech is ‘more’?

Tags: ellipsis, parts-of-speech, quantifiers

> If possible always pay the balance in full every month or pay more than the minimum amount.

What part of speech is ‘more’and which word it is modifying?

Comment: Were there any commas in the original quotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional label is *substantive adjective*.  One way to analyze the sentence is to assume that its modificand has been elided:

> If possible, always pay the balance in full every month or pay more [money] than the minimum amount.

Answer (score 1):

*If possible always pay the balance in full every month or pay **more** than the minimum amount*.

"More" belongs to the category (part of speech) 'determinative': it's the comparative counterpart of the plain "much".

Its function in the clause is that of 'fused determiner-head', where we understand it to mean "more money".

Answer (score -1):

The simple meaning of the sentence translates to:

> Always try to pay the balance with the **correct amount**, or an amount **higher than** the minimal amount, as specified by the speaker (not mentioned here).